# Rails db:seed not populating postgresql on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ubuntu

I have a rails app running in production on an Ubuntu 16.04 server. As far as I can tell, it seems like everything is set up right

- I created a psql user named "rails"
- I made `myapp_name_production` + `_development` & `_test` with the owner set as `rails` (my Ubuntu user)
- I ran `rails db:create` and `rails db:migrate`
- I ran `rails db:seed` but it simply delayed a moment before returning to a new command line.

I configured my `database.yml` like so:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost
  username: postgres
  password: mypassword

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_name_development

production:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_name_production
```

My `seeds.rb` file:

```
news = BlogCategory.create name: "News"
reviews = BlogCategory.create name: "Reviews"
interviews = BlogCategory.create name: "Interviews"
tutorials = BlogCategory.create name: "Tutorials"
noCat = BlogCategory.create name: "No Category"

subcat = BlogCategory.create name: "Audio Industry", parent_id: news.id
subcat = BlogCategory.create name: "Game Audio", parent_id: news.id
subcat = BlogCategory.create name: "Film Audio", parent_id: news.id

subcat = BlogCategory.create name: "Software", parent_id: reviews.id
subcat = BlogCategory.create name: "Hardware", parent_id: reviews.id

subcat = BlogCategory.create name: "Sound Designers", parent_id: interviews.id
subcat = BlogCategory.create name: "Composers", parent_id: interviews.id
subcat = BlogCategory.create name: "Game Developers", parent_id: interviews.id
subcat = BlogCategory.create name: "Voice Talent", parent_id: interviews.id

subcat = BlogCategory.create name: "Sound Design", parent_id: tutorials.id
subcat = BlogCategory.create name: "Composition", parent_id: tutorials.id
subcat = BlogCategory.create name: "Implementation", parent_id: tutorials.id
subcat = BlogCategory.create name: "Voice Acting", parent_id: tutorials.id

Admin = User.create username: "Admin", first_name: "Admin", email: "[email@hotmail.com]", admin: true, password: "[password]", activated: true, slug: "admin"
```

I'm not quite sure what else I need to do, am I missing something?

I also verified that the tables were created by doing the following:

```
$ psql -d myapp_name_production
psql (9.5.13)
Type "help" for help.

myapp_name_production=> \d
                  List of relations
 Schema |           Name           |   Type   | Owner
--------+--------------------------+----------+-------
 public | ar_internal_metadata     | table    | rails
 public | blog_categories          | table    | rails
 public | blog_categories_id_seq   | sequence | rails
 public | ckeditor_assets          | table    | rails
 public | ckeditor_assets_id_seq   | sequence | rails
 public | comments                 | table    | rails
 public | comments_id_seq          | sequence | rails
 public | contacts                 | table    | rails
 public | contacts_id_seq          | sequence | rails
 public | friendly_id_slugs        | table    | rails
 public | friendly_id_slugs_id_seq | sequence | rails
 public | newsletters              | table    | rails
 public | newsletters_id_seq       | sequence | rails
 public | packs                    | table    | rails
 public | packs_id_seq             | sequence | rails
 public | posts                    | table    | rails
 public | posts_id_seq             | sequence | rails
 public | purchases                | table    | rails
 public | purchases_id_seq         | sequence | rails
 public | schema_migrations        | table    | rails
 public | users                    | table    | rails
 public | users_id_seq             | sequence | rails
(22 rows)
```

All of this worked on my computer (windows) on localhost:3000 in development.

**UPDATE:**

My BlogCategory model:

```
class BlogCategory < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
  has_many :posts

  # This is called a self referential relation. This is where records in a table may point to other records in the same table.
  has_many :sub_categories, class_name: "BlogCategory", foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :sub_category_posts, through: :sub_categories, source: :posts
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'BlogCategory', foreign_key: :parent_id
  # This is a scope to load the top level categories and eager-load their posts, subcategories, and the subcategories' posts too.
  scope :top_level, -> { where(parent_id: nil).includes :posts, sub_categories: :posts }

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    slug.nil? || name_changed?
  end

end
```

Comment: just in case, is your file under `db/seeds.rb`?

Comment: Can you paste the whole stacktrace?

Comment: @AlexUnger Yes the file is under `db/seeds.rb` in my app's directory.
@jedi what would I do to get the stacktrace?

Comment: I am sorry, this might be silly but...did you run `rails db:seed`? Run it and paste the output of the command here.

Comment: @jedi Not silly at all, I clearly forget to include it in my process. Yes, I ran `rails db:seed` while in my app directory and it simply paused for a moment before returning to a new line. There was no output in the terminal window.

Comment: Did you set `RAILS_ENV` to use your production environment?

Comment: Just drop `binding.pry` or `debugger` in any of the lines in db/seed.rb file to debug it. In the debugger just make a query to the database to check to see if the records saved. You can also do `subcat = BlogCategory.new name: "Software", parent_id: reviews.id` `subcat.save` `subcat.valid?` to see if the record was valid.

Comment: @jedi or just use `create!` instead of `create`.

Comment: @spickermann I don't think I set the `RAILS_ENV` where would I set it? I can already reach my website through my domain online and I am using Nginx + Passenger if that makes a difference. How would I set the env?

Comment: @jedi I see now. When running it with `create!` I get an error saying: "ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Parent must exist"

Comment: There you go! So now you know the reason. The records were not passing validations.

Comment: @jedi It shouldn't have a parent though. The main category should have parent as `NULL` but I can't seem to figure out how to do that in the seed. I tried doing `parent_id: NULL` and `parent_id: nil` but they both didn't work.

Comment: @spickermann I was able to seed my db with a user using your method, I commented out everything else but the user and I had to change the username/slug to something other than "Admin" for it to work. I have updated my question with my model and a new problem popping up for the `blog_categories` I would be very grateful for your help on this one, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried in your model this?:

```
belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'BlogCategory', foreign_key: :parent_id, optional: true
```

Make the `belongs_to` association optional

Comment: I'm pretty sure this actually worked, I was checking the development db instead, it populated the production one after I changed it but let me check something and see if its what worked.

Comment: Thank you, after recreating my Ubuntu server, I discovered that this is indeed what made my seed successful. Many thanks to @spickermann as well as he pointed out that I had to use `rails db:seed RAILS_ENV='production'` to define where the seed was being sent to.

Answer (score 0):

`"ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Parent must exist"` means that probably the first 5 lines of code failed, which is the reason why other records do not get saved.

Try putting this after `friendly_id :name, use: :slugged` line

```
belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'BlogCategory', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
```

Comment: I've included my model in the question. I should also say that I commented out everything but the first `create!` seed and that is the error I got. the main category should have `parent_id NULL` so I tried without it, with `parent_id: NULL` and `parent_id: nil` none worked.

Comment: What version of Rails do you have?

Comment: I'm using Rails 5.1.6